# Where do I get the 'environ' parameter for Werkzeug's send_file?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

Werkzeug 2.0 has a [`send_file`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/utils/#werkzeug.utils.send_file) method that [Flask's `send_file`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.send_file) wraps.

One of its parameters is `environ` and its description is "(WSGIEnvironment) - The WSGI environ for the current request."

Where do I get this value to pass in my code?

```
from flask import Flask, request
from werkzeug.utils import send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/download/<string:filename>")
def download(filename):
    return send_file(filename, environ=...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Flask, use Flask's `send_file`, not Werkzeug's. Flask wraps Werkzeug's version to add Flask-specific behavior, including automatically passing the environ.

Also, with Flask or Werkzeug, do not use `send_file` to send arbitrary paths supplied by users, this is unsafe. Use `send_from_directory` to limit the top-level directory that the path can point to.

```py
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route("/download/<path:path>")
def download(path):
    return send_from_directory("uploads", path)
```

---

If you *are* using Werkzeug only, you either have the environ from the WSGI callable, or from the `Request` object with `request.environ`. Since Werkzeug doesn't have a `request` global like Flask does, you need to pass it manually to `send_file`.

```py
from werkzeug import Request
from werkzeug.utils import send_from_directory

@Request.application
def app(request):
    return send_from_directory("uploads", request.path, environ=request.environ)
```